# What Operating System is installed on each partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, operating-systems

I have an SSD drive with two partitions - one with Windows 8 installed, which I bought a few years ago and the other with windows 10 (upgraded from windows 7).

I have a problem with Windows 10.  I want to try this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/automatic-repair-loop-on-start-on-windows-81/e3369ec8-e2a2-42de-9f1c-f043e812e4d9

However, I cannot remember whether windows 10 is installed on the C:\ or the F:.  Is there a way I can find out? I have read a few questions on here were people recommend looking in: system32/license.txt, however that has not given anything away.

I have run the following DOS command whilst logged into windows 8:

```
Echo %windir%
```

This returns: c:\windows.  Can I assume that Windows 10 is installed on the F:\ on that basis?

Comment: You should search not for the name of partition, but for its order. Each windows should call `C:\\ ` the partition on which it is installed (at least on old windows system it was possible). The equivalent of Linux `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`, where `sda1` is the 1st partition of the disk `sda`... Probably from the tools that allow you to resize the partitions and to do the defrag you can read it. You can use [disk managment](http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=305)

Comment: @Hastur, what do you mean by the order?

Comment: Go on start and write `computer management` in windows 7, `disk management` for windows 8... and start it. After a while it loads the situation of your HDD, with the relative partitions. [For order I meant number]

Comment: @Hastur, I realise that.  However, it does not tell you what version of windows is installed on each partition unless I am mistaken.

Comment: can you elaborate on the reasoning, why when you see `c:\windows` you assume windows 10 is on F?  i'm not saying it is or it isn't,, just asking for your reasoning